# How find the azure cloud blob details

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, azure

```
    List<com.vikas.aws.model.S3Object> objects = new ArrayList<com.vikas.aws.model.S3Object>();
    ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest(getBucketName(),
            String.join("", URL_MEDIA, URL_ORGS, orgId, FORWARD), null, FORWARD,
            (size == null ? getMaxKeys() : size));
    ObjectListing listing = getAmazonS3Client().listObjects(request);
    if (listing != null) {
        List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();
        for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : summaries) {

            if (!s3ObjectSummary.getKey().contains(Optional.ofNullable(search).orElse(FORWARD))) {
                continue;
            }

            com.vikas.aws.model.S3Object s3Obj = new com.vikas.aws.model.S3Object();
            s3Obj.setOrgId(orgId);
            s3Obj.setBucketName(s3ObjectSummary.getBucketName());
            s3Obj.setKey(s3ObjectSummary.getKey());
            s3Obj.setPublicUrl(getMediaPublicUrl(s3ObjectSummary.getKey()));
            s3Obj.seteTag(s3ObjectSummary.getETag());
            s3Obj.setSize(s3ObjectSummary.getSize());
            s3Obj.setLastModified(s3ObjectSummary.getLastModified());
            s3Obj.setStorageClass(s3ObjectSummary.getStorageClass());
            objects.add(s3Obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Currently my project work aws s3 amazon storage, i want change it with azure blob storage, but i implemented so many thing like upload, delete, and download blobs, create container, but due to some requirement i want get blobs details which is in above code with s3 amazon, how will achieve it with azure blob.

Comment: The code above is doing too many things. Can you please update your question and explain what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: please look again my code.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/. This should help you getting started with Blob Storage using Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and description, I think you want to find some mapping relationship from AWS S3 Storage to Azure Blob Storage.

As @GauravMantri said, I recommend to view the offical doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/ too.

Meanwhile, you can get the blob details via class [`CloudBlob`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html)/[`BlobProperties`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobProperties.html) and `CloudBlob.getMetadata()`, please refer to their API references via Javadocs and view the their REST API references below to get more information.

1. Get Blob Properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179394.aspx
2. Get Blob Metadata https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179350.aspx

Hope it helps.